# Where can I ask about Audio Production?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Recently I started to have some fun on [Video Production Stack Exchange](http://video.stackexchange.com), and I've started to wonder why no audio.stackexchange.com exists where topics such as:

- Software: Avid ProTools, Adobe Audition, Adobe Soundbooth, VST plugins..
- Hardware: All audio related hardware including the avid and old digidesign ones, their configuration, firmwares and so on
- Audio Codecs, compression, transcoding, best practices

and so on could be asked?

Where could I ask such questions on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Sound Design is a site dedicated to questions and answers about
> professional sound design and production.
>
> Questions that are on topic include questions about:
>
> - sound design in the film and video game industries
> - live production audio
> - mixing and recording in a studio from the perspective of the sound tech
> - field recording
>
> As long as your question is about one of these topics and is:
>
> - detailed and specific
> - written clearly and simply
> - of interest to at least one other person interested in sound design
>
> ... it is welcome here.

The site exists, but instead of your presumed `audio.stackexchange`, it's `sound.stackexchange` :)

Before asking, please check the help center; I've quoted their on-topic, but please do have a look around once!

Note: they do have the [vst](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vst), [pro-tools](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-tools), [adobe-audition](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-audition), [compression](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression), etc... tags there, as you said in the question

Comment: Fun, i expected audio because audio/video production was the original fork of the website, never tough of searching sound!